# numpy Structured arrays append and remove records

Tags: python, numpy, structured-array

let's say  we have  this  structured array  :

```
x = np.array([('Rex', 9, 81.0), ('Fido', 3, 27.0)],
dtype=[('name', 'U10'), ('age', 'i4'), ('weight', 'f4')])
```

how to delete  the first row  :('Rex', 9, 81.0)  ?
and how add another row   ??

Comment: you question is unclear… 1.`x[1:]`?

Comment: you can transform it as a list: X = list(x) and to remove you can just use del X[0] and to add you can use (append or insert) and after that transform it again as numpy array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you wanting this: *(with [`np.insert`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html#numpy.insert))*

```
>>> x = np.array([('Rex', 9, 81.0), ('Fido', 3, 27.0)],dtype=[('name', 'U10'), ('age', 'i4'), ('weight', 'f4')])

>>> y = np.array([('sam', 10, 100.0)],dtype=[('name', 'U10'), ('age', 'i4'), ('weight', 'f4')])

>>> np.insert(x[1:],0,y)
array([('sam', 10, 100.), ('Fido',  3,  27.)],
      dtype=[('name', '<U10'), ('age', '<i4'), ('weight', '<f4')])
```

Or with [`np.append`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html#numpy.append) and [`np.delete`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html):

```
>>> x = np.delete(x, 1, axis=0)
>>> np.append(x, y, axis=0)
array([('Rex',  9,  81.), ('sam', 10, 100.)],
      dtype=[('name', '<U10'), ('age', '<i4'), ('weight', '<f4')])
```

Comment: yes that is want i wanted thank you

Comment: @NAS welcome dude ;)